# Cleaning Up Multiple Pipenv Environments

Tags: django, pycharm, pipenv

I have a Django project that I set up via PyCharm. Since it was set up, I've moved it and renamed it. In the process, I think I created multiple pipenv environments. The reason I think so is that there are two entries under preferences/Project:xyz/Project Interpreter. One is listed as:

```
xyz/venv/bin/python.
```

The other is:

```
~/.local/share/virtualenvs/xyz-1IjVbwgz/bin/phton.
```

I replaced the real project name with xyz. The one local to the project has problems installing and uninstalling mysqlclient. Pycharm says it adds or deletes it, but it remains displayed.

I just executed "pipenv shell" on the command line and got this response:

> Launching subshell in virtual environment…
>    . /Users/curt/.local/share/virtualenvs/xyz-1IjVbwgz/bin/activate
>   ➜  merrittsecurity  . /Users/curt/.local/share/virtualenvs/xyz-1IjVbwgz/bin/activate

It would appear the one in .local/share is the correct one. So a few questions. Is this the normal location for pipenv? I'm on MacOS Mojave. Can I safely delete the one local to the project? There is an option in PyCharm to do that. The project runs fine. I just want to clean it up before using Docker with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the default location is  `~/.local/share/virtualenvs`, you can delete the local one.

You can change the default location by setting the `PIPENV_VENV_IN_PROJECT` environment variable,

```
 export PIPENV_VENV_IN_PROJECT=true
```

This will create the virtual environment `.venv` within your project folder.

> MyProject
>
> `>`.venv
>
> `>` MyProject
>
> `>` Pipfile
>
> `>` Pipfile.lock

-

This should be a neat way of handling your virtualenvs, instead of creating it somewhere.

Comment: Did you mean venv and not .venv? I have the venv directory without the dot. I've had it before do anything in your answer.